# Does spring support loading bootstrap.yml file from spring cloud config/http url?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

Does spring support loading bootstrap.yml file from spring cloud config/http url? Or does it require the bootstrap file to be present in the classpath?

Answer (score 1):

`bootstrap.yml` cannot be loaded from the Spring Cloud Config Server. `bootstrap.yml` gets used to populate the `bootstrap` context, which in turn is used to populate the application context with the configuration properties coming from Spring Cloud Config Server. `bootstrap.yml` must be available to the Spring Boot application locally (classpath, local file...).